# Can i safely migrate to pnpm from yarn

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json, pnpm, yarn-v2

I am currently staying at a location where internet and disk space are at a premium and yarn/npm constantly having to install module every single time isn't the most efficient use of both my disk space and internet data which bring me to my question,
I recently came across pnpm and it perfectly solves my problem (it install modules in a central location and symlink them to your projects), my question is this if i completely migrate to pnpm will that affect the project setup if i was working with someone using yarn/ npm for instance and if i publish a project will the users be forced to use pnpm or they can use any package manager

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to pick one package manager for a project and force its usage by everyone. pnpm, yarn, npm all have their own lockfiles.

If it is a small project and you don't commit the lockfile, then you may use different package managers. But I still don't recommend this.